# With python's xml elementTree, how to get the schema location of an xml?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Given the following root xml element:

```
<shiporder orderid="889923" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="data.xsd">
```

I want to extract the name of the `xsd` file, which would be `data.xsd`.

However, when using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse the file that contains the line above, I get these attributes:

```
et_data = et.parse("data.xml")

root = et_data.getroot()

print(root.attrib)

{'orderid': '889923', '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': 'data.xsd'}
```

- How do I manage to get the schema location without depending of the xsi value ?
- If not possible, what is the correct way to extract the schema location ?

Answer (score 0):

As you notice, ElementTree has already taken care of getting rid of the `xsi` namespace reference for you (there's no sign of `xsi` in `root.attrib`, is there?)

The namespaced attribute name for the `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute defined by the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` schema is `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation`, so you access it with

```
root.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation']
```

Comment: Is it possible that xmlns:xsi gets a different value at some point ?

Comment: No, it would break the internet if it changed.

Comment: Your document could use `xmlns:kjdsfgkjansfguonrwijunaefrshg` and `kjdsfgkjansfguonrwijunaefrshg:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` if it liked. `xsi` is just an arbitrary alias. The value `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` is the well-known URI for XML Schemas.